# How to upload multiple upload form element in Codeigniter3?

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload

I'm creating multiple upload images using multiple form upload element in form **Codeigniter3** form helper.
I have 4 upload_form to upload data as below

1. eng_up_img
2. kh_up_img
3. ch_up_img
4. fr_up_img

I've used these field for upload all the different images for form elements to DB with image properties.

**Issues** I don't understand how to post data from each form element to PHP variables and how to fetch those field from form .

Here is my form

```
 <?PHP echo form_open_multipart('', array('id' => 'eng_form')); ?>
 <?PHP echo form_upload('eng_up_img', '', 'class="" id="eng_up_img" '); ?>
 <?PHP echo form_upload('kh_up_img', '', 'class="" id="kh_up_img" '); ?>
 <?PHP echo form_upload('ch_up_img', '', 'class="" id="ch_up_img" '); ?>
 <?PHP echo form_upload('fr_up_img', '', 'class="" id="fr_up_img" '); ?>
 <?PHP echo form_close(); ?>
```

And Here is Controller function

```
public function upload() {

        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
        $config['upload_path'] = '../assets/img/slide';
        $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
        $config['max_size'] = '1000000';
        $config['max_width'] = '102400';
        $config['max_height'] = '768000';
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        $token = $this->security->get_csrf_hash();

        $res = FALSE;
        $img_data = array(
            'eng_up_img' => $this->upload->do_upload('eng_up_img'),
            'kh_up_img' => $this->upload->do_upload('kh_up_img'),
            'ch_up_img' => $this->upload->do_upload('ch_up_img'),
            'fr_up_img' => $this->upload->do_upload('fr_up_img'),
        );
        if (!$img_data['eng_up_img'] && !$img_data['kh_up_img'] && !$img_data['ch_up_img'] && !$img_data['fr_up_img']) {
            $res = FALSE;
        } else {
            $eng_up_img = $this->upload->data();
            $kh_up_img = $this->upload->data();
            $ch_up_img = $this->upload->data();
            $fr_up_img = $this->upload->data();
        }
        echo json_encode(array('res' => $res, 'img_pro' => $data, 'token' => $token));
    }
```

I hope Friend can help me thanks

Comment: Why Do I got only the last of form_upload ?

Answer (score 1):

I think the reason why you get the last form_upload only is, because they all share the same name.
try to update your view like that:

```
$arrLanguagePrefix = array("eng","kh","ch","fr");
echo form_open_multipart('', array('id' => 'eng_form')); 

foreach($arrLanguagePrefix AS $value)
{
    $arrData = array
    (
        "id" => $value."_up_img",
        "name" => $value."_up_img"
    );

    echo form_upload($arrData);
}
echo form_close();
```

Answer (score 0):

I have Codeigniter Helper for Uploading file, may be this helps you

```
function sf_upload($nama_gambar, $lokasi_gambar, $tipe_gambar, $ukuran_gambar, $name_file_form) {
    $CI                    = &get_instance();
    $nmfile                = $nama_gambar . "_" . time();
    $config['upload_path'] = './' . $lokasi_gambar;
    //tambahi skrip disini is_dir exist
    $config['allowed_types'] = $tipe_gambar;
    $config['max_size']      = $ukuran_gambar;
    $config['file_name']     = $nmfile;
    $CI->load->library('upload', $config);
    $CI->upload->do_upload($name_file_form);
    // die($CI->upload->display_errors());
    $result1 = $CI->upload->data();
    $result  = ['gambar' => $result1];
    $dfile   = $result['gambar']['file_name'];
    
        return $dfile; 
}
```